# Error loading war to tomcat6

Tags: eclipse, zip, tomcat6, war, bonecp

I'm attempting to load my war file to Tomcat 6 and constantly get this error:

> May 20, 2014 12:35:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig
>   init
>           SEVERE: Exception fixing docBase for context [/MyService] 
>           java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
>             at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
>
> ...
>
> May 20, 2014 12:35:42 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resourcesStart
>           SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
>           java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid or unreadable WAR file : error in opening zip file

I've found several suggestions and tried them all, still stumped.

- Moved the file to a diff directory, then copied to webapps
- Changed the file permissions before moving to webapps
- Stopped Tomcat, delete the old, add the new, then restart
- Added a random class to the war before re-deploying
- Uninstalled tomcat6 (also removing the tomcat6 directory) and re-installed tomcat6 fully

Here's the strangest part - I've also taken old wars (older versions of the same app) that used to work on this same server, and those don't work either (same error), even after re-installing Tomcat.  This leads me to believe it's a Tomcat problem, however the uninstall didn't fix anything.
Also, I've created war files from this same project (Eclipse) and deployed them fine to a different tomcat6 server.  Also, when I run the app on my dev box localhost Eclipse/Tomcat connecting to the same database remotely, everything works fine.

When I actually make an http request, the app is deployed, however I have a static initializer that is not working and causing a null pointer exception.  I assume this is related to the

> SEVERE: Error starting static Resources

Here is the static initializer, it is creating a BoneCP connection pool, which also has always worked and I confirmed that MySQL is working fine (replication is also still occurring - it is a slave MySQL).  The connectionPool object is null and I don't get a stack trace in my logs for the openPool() method, I also don't see any root connections to MySQL:

```
protected static BoneCP connectionPool = null;

static
{
    openPool();
}

protected static void openPool()
{
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        BoneCPConfig config = new BoneCPConfig();

        config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase"); 
        config.setUsername("root"); 
        config.setPassword("mypassword"); //SLAVE

        config.setMinConnectionsPerPartition(2);
        config.setMaxConnectionsPerPartition(6);
        config.setPartitionCount(7);
        connectionPool = new BoneCP(config);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welp, I figured this out...
Somehow the password for the mysql root user was changed, which is very odd since I'm the ONLY person that ever touches any of this.  I have a feeling MySQLWorkbench somehow did this without me knowing?  I just recently installed a new version (6.1).
Basically this seems to be a catch all error, which I saw some people mention on other threads, so I've been on a 4 day wild goose chase.  The only reason I figured this out was because I finally tried to log in to mysql as root through the console, in retrospect I should have tried that earlier.

Comment: Do I not get my bounty points back for answering my own question??!!

Comment: No, you can't award the bounty to your own answer. See [How does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/204841)